# messageHash hash function

Tags: web3js, signature, hash

In this example, by which algorithm is messageHash hashed by?

`web3.eth.accounts.sign("Hello, world!", '0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef')
{ message: 'Hello, world!',
  messageHash: '0xb453bd4e271eed985cbab8231da609c4ce0a9cf1f763b6c1594e76315510e0f1',
  v: '0x1b',
  r: '0x3bc843a917d6c19c487c1d0c660cdd61389ce2a7651ee3171bcc212ffddca164',
  s: '0x193f1f2e06f7ed8f9fbf2254232d99848a8102b552032b68a5507b4d81492f0f',
  signature: '0x3bc843a917d6c19c487c1d0c660cdd61389ce2a7651ee3171bcc212ffddca164193f1f2e06f7ed8f9fbf2254232d99848a8102b552032b68a5507b4d81492f0f1b' }`

Comment: I think it must be sha3 or sha256. It could also be keccak256.

Comment: none of them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is explained in web3 documentation for [web3.eth.accounts.hashMessage(message)](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#hashmessage)

> Hashes the given message to be passed `web3.eth.accounts.recover()` function. The data will be UTF-8 HEX decoded and enveloped as follows: `"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + message.length + message` and hashed using **keccak256**.